# Enabling LDAPS (636) on Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2019

I've got a configuration issue with my test domain controller (Server 2019) where I can't connect via 636 using LDP. (using the full domain name)

On 2008 and 2012 I didn't have to do any additional configuration; it just worked.

However, in 2019 is may appear that I need to manually configure an SSL cert for this to work.  I found this article on MS: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/enable-ldap-over-ssl-3rd-certification-authority  and it appears that I need to get a public certificate for each domain that I will be connecting to (which will be a lot).  If this is true, those certs would expire and I'm not sure what the effect will be (will it still work or fail?).  If it will fail, how do I watch the certs and fix ahead of time?

But this doesn't make sense to me since 2008 and 2012 both work "out of the box" with 636.

When I check the 2019 server with:
certutil -v -urlfetch -verify serverssl.cer > output.txt

I get:

DecodeFile returned The system cannot find the file specified 0x80070002 (Win32: 2 ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
LoadCert(Cert) returned The system cannot find the file specified 0x80070002 (Win32: 2 ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
CertUtil -verify command FAILED: 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2 ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
CertUtil: The system cannot find the file specified.

So that's telling me the cert does not exist.

Each of the domains I will be connecting to, the computer connecting to them will not be in the same domain.  In that above article it was referring to having a cert that can be trusted by both devices.

From the testdomain I can run LDP and connect back into the 2008 or 2012 domain with zero issues on 636 using the builtin configured certificate... But this is a new version and it appears to be different.

Has anyone run into this on 2019 and can share a little more information of what I'm encountering?

Comment: Do you use an internal-only name for your AD domain (such as `domain.local`) or a public one?

Comment: For my test environment they are all .local domains

Comment: Then you can't get public certificates for them. You'll have to set up an internal Certification Authority.

Comment: Ah good point!  That lead me to check on the freshly installed domain if I had the certificate authority set up and I didn't.  Once I installed and configured the cert authority it started working. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out my issue was that in the test domain I didn't install the cert authority service.  Once installed and configured, it started working as expected.

Comment: Please note that certificates signed by an internal CA will only be automatically accepted by domain members; if you need something that's *not* a domain member (such a network device or a non-domain computer) to trust them, you'll have to explicitly trust the CA's root certificate.